# IIS Application Pool recycle after appsettings.config change

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Is the application pool automatically recycled after the appsettings.config file has been changed (and saved)? I'm asking because I want to know whether I should recycle manually or not.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Modifying the appconfig.config file or pushing out a fresh copy of any DLL files will trigger a refresh of the app pool for your application.

Comment: I have trouble believing this. Wouldn't an app pool refresh kill my Session? I am able to update appSettings.config without doing so.

Comment: It depends on what was in your session. If you're using SQL Server based sessions, or have some  way in your code to start up the session again based on a cookie, then you'll be fine. Otherwise you may have some of your session details (form fields, login name, etc.), but behind the scenes a new session has started.